# I am trying to make the tabs of an asp.net wizard clickable links but it doesn't seem to work

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wizard

I found a great asp.net wizard template online that moves the wizard steps from the side to the top. It how ever does not have click functionality when it is on top. I am trying to make the tabs clickable links but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is a snippet of the wizard:

```
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" BorderColor="#FFFBD6" BorderStyle="Solid" 
         BorderWidth="2px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="0.9em" ForeColor="#333333" 
         HorizontalAlign="Center" />

     <HeaderTemplate>
           <ul id="wizHeader">
               <asp:Repeater ID="SideBarList" runat="server">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                      <li><a class="<%# GetClassForWizardStep(Container.DataItem) %>"     
      title="<%#Eval("Name")%>">
                           <%# Eval("Name")%></a> </li>
                   </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:Repeater>
           </ul>
       </HeaderTemplate>

        <NavigationButtonStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" 
         BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="1.2em"
         ForeColor="#990000" CssClass="centerButtons" />

     <SideBarButtonStyle ForeColor="White" />
     <SideBarStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Size="0.9em" VerticalAlign="Top" />
    <WizardSteps>
```

And here is some of the code behind:

```
Private Sub wizClaims_PreRender(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles  
    wizClaims.PreRender
    Dim SideBarList As Repeater = 
        TryCast(wizClaims.FindControl("HeaderContainer").FindControl("SideBarList"), 
           Repeater)
    SideBarList.DataSource = wizClaims.WizardSteps
    SideBarList.DataBind()
End Sub

Public Function GetClassForWizardStep(wizardStep As Object) As String
    Dim [step] As WizardStep = TryCast(wizardStep, WizardStep)

    If [step] Is Nothing Then
        Return ""
    End If
    Dim stepIndex As Integer = wizClaims.WizardSteps.IndexOf([step])

    If stepIndex < wizClaims.ActiveStepIndex Then
        Return "prevStep"
    ElseIf stepIndex > wizClaims.ActiveStepIndex Then
        Return "nextStep"
    Else
        Return "currentStep"
    End If
End Function
```

I would appreciate any help :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest solution in my opinion:

1. Use a `<linkbutton>` instead of an `<a>`, so that a postback will be generated:

   ```
   <asp:LinkButton runat="server" 
   CssClass="<%# GetClassForWizardStep(Container.DataItem) %>">
      <%# Eval("Name")%>
   </asp:LinkButton>
   ```
2. Attach an event to the repeater:

   ```
   <asp:Repeater ID="SideBarList" runat="server" 
     OnItemCommand="SideBarList_ItemCommand">
   ```
3. In the code behind, respond to the event:

   ```
   Protected Sub SideBarList_ItemCommand(source As Object, 
                                         e As RepeaterCommandEventArgs)
     wizClaims.ActiveStepIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex
   End Sub
   ```

Now clicking any of the link buttons will change the active step of your wizard.